# Duplicate hover Info in plotly with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a code that uses the plotly and ggplot2. When I hover the info the information inside is duplicated meaning that it show 2 same TrendName Info lines for all of the graphs. for example this is what it is showing in the hover info

Month_Names: 2011-05
Actual_volume: 56488
TrendName: 2010-11 - 2017-01
TrendName: 2010-11 - 2017-01

How do I show only 1 TrendName?  Thanks

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

Month_Names <- c("2010-11","2010-12",
             "2011-01","2011-02","2011-03","2011-04","2011-05","2011-06","2011-07","2011-08","2011-09","2011-10","2011-11","2011-12",
             "2012-01","2012-02","2012-03","2012-04","2012-05","2012-06","2012-07","2012-08","2012-09","2012-10","2012-11","2012-12",
             "2013-01","2013-02","2013-03","2013-04","2013-05","2013-06","2013-07","2013-08","2013-09","2013-10","2013-11","2013-12",
             "2014-01","2014-02","2014-03","2014-04","2014-05","2014-06","2014-07","2014-08","2014-09","2014-10","2014-11","2014-12",
             "2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-05","2015-06","2015-07","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11","2015-12",
             "2016-01","2016-02","2016-03","2016-04","2016-05","2016-06","2016-07","2016-08","2016-09","2016-10","2016-11","2016-12",
             "2017-01")
Actual_volume <- c(54447,57156,
               52033,49547,58718,53109,56488,60095,54683,60863,56692,55283,55504,56633,
               53267,52587,54680,55569,60013,56985,59709,61281,54188,59832,56489,55819,
               59295,52692,56663,59698,61232,57694,63111,60473,58984,64050,54957,63238,
               59460,54430,58901,61088,60496,62984,66895,62720,65591,67815,58289,72002,
               61054,60329,69283,68002,63196,72267,71058,69539,71379,70925,68704,76956,
               65863,70494,77348,70214,74770,77480,69721,83034,76761,77927,79768,81836,
               75381)

df_data <- data.frame(Month_Names, Actual_volume) 

trendDateRange1 <- c("2010-11-01", "2017-01-31")
trendDateRange2 <- c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")
trendDateRange3 <- c("2013-01-01", "2013-12-31")
numoftrends <- 3

trends <- data_frame(Start = c("2010-11", "2012-01", "2013-01"),
                 End = c("2017-01", "2012-12", "2013-12"))
combined_data <- df_data %>%
                 crossing(trends) %>%
                 mutate(Month_Names = as.character(Month_Names),
TrendName = paste(Start, End, sep = "-")) %>%
            filter(Month_Names >= Start,
                  Month_Names <= End)

p <- ggplot(combined_data, aes(Month_Names, y = Actual_volume,
                           group = TrendName,
                           color = TrendName)) +
     geom_line() +
     labs(x=" ",y=" ") +
     labs(title = "New plot title") +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", color="blue", 
                              size=18),
     legend.title = element_blank(),
     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
     )

ggplotly(p) %>% 
     layout(title = "New plot title", 
            legend = list(orientation = "h",x = 0.25, y = -.75),  
            annotations = list()
           )
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've 4 variables in the `aes` when you build your `ggplot` object.  When you use `ggplotly` it will use all mapped aesthetics in the tooltip.

To remove the duplicate caused by `group` and `color` you need to specify what items to use in the tooltip as a character vector. (Note the spelling on colour, and you can also use `group` instead).

```
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("x","y","colour")) %>% 
  layout(title = "New plot title", 
         legend = list(orientation = "h",x = 0.25, y = -.75)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Jake Kaupp. I didn't know since  I am new to R, ggplot2 and plotly. Have a great day!